# preg_match(): Unknown modifier

Tags: php, regex

Currently using the following string as my pattern. (Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '0')

```
$between = preg_match("(.*)".$check."(.*)", _allbetween($coords1, $coords2));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Have never used regular expressions in php before, please excuse this probably extremely simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add delimiters to your pattern and use preg_quote if $check contains a literal string:

```
preg_match("/(.*)".preg_quote($check)."(.*)/", _allbetween($coords1, $coords2));
```

Note that preg_match returns 1 or 0 (true or false), not the match result (see the [php manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php))

Comment: This works perfectly. I'll be selecting your answer for simplicity!

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression in PHP must be enclosed by a pair of characters, that do not occur in the regexp itself (and if, they mus be escaped using a backslash).

Which character you use is defined through the first char – a `(` in your case. But a bracket already has a special meaning in regexp.

You should enclose your regexp by the most common delimiter `/` (a slash), as in:

```
$between = preg_match( sprintf( '/(.*)%s(.*)/', preg_quote( $check ) ), _allbetween($coords1, $coords2));
```

- see: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php
- and maybe also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php as you should always escape user inputs to regular expression (if `$check` is one…)